# How do I end a process using Visual Basic?

Tags: vbscript, kill, kill-process

Basically, I've made a program that has both "RUN BOT" and "KILL BOT" buttons. My question is what code do I use to 'Kill' the bot or in other terms close out the "batchfile.bat" that it's running when the button "RUN BOT" is clicked. Appreciate all future help!

[image: The App with both buttons]

Here is the code so far:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Process.Start("C:\batchfile.bat")
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please do not link to other sites. This can be considered shameless self-promotion and/or spam. Please make an effort to describe the problem in the question itself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Store the Process instance that the method Process.Start() returns, in an instance variable. Then, call [CloseMainWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), or [Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), the one that better suits your need.

EDIT: This works in VS 2010

```
Public Class Form1
Private p As Process

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    p = Process.Start("c:\batchfile.bat")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    p.Kill()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Process.Start("C:\batchfile.bat")
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Process.Start("C:\batchfile.bat").Kill()
    End Sub
End Class Is this what you mean? Because this doesn't work.

Comment: @user2082130 I've just edited my response, to clarify it. Hope that helps.

Comment: i'm not sure how to set that up? whenever i try to set that script/code up properly i receive squiggles and errors.