# Killing an existing process

Tags: vb.net, process, kill

I am trying to build a script that starts, and later stops a process:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Process.Start("C:\batchfile.bat")
    End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles 
    (DESIRED CODE HERE)
    End Sub
End Class
```

`Button2` starts the process for `batchfile.bat`.  I need to find a way to end this process when `Button1` is clicked.  Is there a relatively simple way to do this?

Comment: If you don't know how to do it, why do you think it shouldn't be a lot of code?  The arrogance in this question won't get you much help.

Comment: The question doesn't seem arrogant to me.

Comment: I just edited it to make it a bit more clear and straightforward.

Comment: Wasn't arrogant one bit, but i suppose it's all interpreted by the reader. Anyways, next time don't edit so much of a text, you left out information that was needed. Did not fully appreciate that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to End a Process using Visual Basic (Help)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989531/how-to-end-a-process-using-visual-basic-help)

Answer (score 1):

Please check this sample code

```
  Dim p1 As Process
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        p1 = Process.Start("C:\Users\082043\Desktop\akshay.bat")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        p1.Kill()
    End Sub
```

Comment: I receive an issue with p1.Kill()

Comment: can u please share the sample for Bat file, in my environment, there is no issue. use p1 must be declared at class Level.

Comment: I have used this sample. in this , I can able to kill the process after timeout, @ECHO OFF
echo "1 Link"
start /d "C:\Users\082043\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application" chrome.exe www.bing.com
timeout /t 10
echo "2 Link"
start /d "C:\Users\082043\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application" chrome.exe www.bing.com
timeout /t 10
echo "3 Link"
start /d "C:\Users\082043\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application" chrome.exe www.bing.com
timeout /t 10

Comment: Site is blocked here.. please share the some scripts in Bat file, so that I can test here

Comment: The bat file is custom so it wouldn't help you testing it.

Comment: Can u please tell me the issue. Kill() will stop the Process.