# VB How do I end a batchfile/cmd command running with a button?

Tags: vb.net, cmd

This is the code i'm using:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
Process.Start("C:\batchfile.bat")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
End Sub
```

I'd like to know how to make Button1_Click kill the "batchfile.bat?" The batchfile is opening a CMD prompt, if that helps anyone in anyway.

Comment: You should name your controls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to End a Process using Visual Basic (Help)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989531/how-to-end-a-process-using-visual-basic-help)

Answer (score 2):

You need to start the `Process` instance returned by `Process.Start()` in a field in your form.

You can then call the `Kill()` method.

For example:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private mySubTask As Process

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        mySubTask = Process.Start("C:\batchfile.bat")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        mySubTask.Kill()
    End Sub
```

You will need to figure out what to do if the user clicks start twice.

Comment: mind showing me in a script? i'm new an don't quite understand. thanks.

Comment: Well, i used that script and it went through as possible, BUT.. it doesn't kill it.